# Proof appearing in the middle of the equations

Tags: formatting, proof-package

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

```
\begin{proof}
\begin{aligned} 
\bar{p} \cdot \bar{x} 
& =\bar{p}^\mu \bar{x}_\mu \\ 
& =\Lambda^\mu{ }_\nu p^\nu \Lambda_\mu{ }^\rho x_p \\ 
& =\left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^\rho{ }_\mu \Lambda^\mu{ }_\nu p^\nu x_p \\ 
& =\delta_\nu^\rho p^\nu x_\rho \\
& =p^\nu x_\nu \\ & =p \cdot x

\end{aligned}
\end{proof}
```

[image]

Comment: aligned is an inline expression, vertically centered like `tabular`, use `\begin{aligned}[t]` for top align

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not show us code as image - we can not copy and test it. Show always short compilable TeX code, copy paste it in your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`aligned` has to be in math mode, and you want top alignment, but I'd use `align*` here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

aligned c
\begin{proof}
$\begin{aligned} 
\bar{p} \cdot \bar{x} 
& =\bar{p}^\mu \bar{x}_\mu \\ 
& =\Lambda^\mu{ }_\nu p^\nu \Lambda_\mu{ }^\rho x_p \\ 
& =\left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^\rho{ }_\mu \Lambda^\mu{ }_\nu p^\nu x_p \\ 
& =\delta_\nu^\rho p^\nu x_\rho \\
& =p^\nu x_\nu \\ & =p \cdot x
\end{aligned}$
\end{proof}

aligned t
\begin{proof}
$\begin{aligned}[t] 
\bar{p} \cdot \bar{x} 
& =\bar{p}^\mu \bar{x}_\mu \\ 
& =\Lambda^\mu{ }_\nu p^\nu \Lambda_\mu{ }^\rho x_p \\ 
& =\left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^\rho{ }_\mu \Lambda^\mu{ }_\nu p^\nu x_p \\ 
& =\delta_\nu^\rho p^\nu x_\rho \\
& =p^\nu x_\nu \\ & =p \cdot x
\end{aligned}$
\end{proof}


Align
\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
\bar{p} \cdot \bar{x} 
& =\bar{p}^\mu \bar{x}_\mu \\ 
& =\Lambda^\mu{ }_\nu p^\nu \Lambda_\mu{ }^\rho x_p \\ 
& =\left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^\rho{ }_\mu \Lambda^\mu{ }_\nu p^\nu x_p \\ 
& =\delta_\nu^\rho p^\nu x_\rho \\
& =p^\nu x_\nu \\ & =p \cdot x \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```